# Find pair of matches between an numpy array Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array in Python which contains labels for a classification problem. The array derived after the concatentation of two initial identical arrays.

```
labels = np.concatenate((labels1, labels2)) #labels1 and labels2 are identical
```

I want to generate positive/negative pairs which will contain all the indexes from labels (from which labels1 and labels2 are equal) and also the pairs with the negative ones. For example if my input is the following:

```
labels = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3} # labels1 = labels2 = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3}
```

Then I want to return as positive pairs:

```
positive_pairs = {{1, 6}, {1, 7}, {2, 6}, {2, 7}, {3, 8}, {3, 9}, {4, 8}, {4, 9}, {5, 10}} # i dont want to have {1,2} or {3, 4} in within the positives
negative_pairs = {{1, 8}, {1, 9}, ...}
```

How can I do so in python?

**EDIT:** What in the case that labels1 and labels2 are not equal?

Comment: Hi, excuse me do you want your output to be a numpy 2D array or some other type ?

Comment: It does not really matter. Ideally I want 4 matrices a, b, c, d where a b to be the positive pairs and c,d the negative ones.

Comment: It is not clear at all what "positive" and "negative" means in the context of "pairs". Also, what do the elements of the pairs represent? For example, what does 1 AND 6 mean in `{1,6}` in `positive_pairs`.

Comment: The elements represent the indexes from the array labels than have the same value (or they dont have they same value). Check my example.

Comment: Also there is the contraint that those pairs needs to be between labels1 and labels2 and not within labels1 or within labels2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution for `positive_pairs`:

```
labels1 = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3])
length1 = len(labels1)
positive_pairs = []
for ii, label in enumerate(labels1, 1):
    for other in np.where(labels1 == label)[0] + length1 + 1:
        positive_pairs.append((ii, other))
```

`negative_pairs` is left as an exercise.

Comment: What if the two matrices labels1 and labels2 are not equal?

Comment: @JoseRamon: I don't know, that's not what was asked in the question.  I guess you can reason out the case you're asking about now.

Comment: I am really sure that I can follow the way that enumerates works. Ans also in my case I need to change labels1 since not I am not duplicate twice the same array.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish it like this

```
labels_1 = np.array([1,1,2,2,3])
labels_2 = np.array([1,1,2,2,3])
n = len(labels_1)
positive_pairs = [(i1+1, i2+n+1) for i1, l in enumerate(labels_1) 
                                 for i2 in np.where(labels_2 == l)[0]]
```

> [(1,6),(1,7),(2,6),(2,7),...]

```
negative_pairs = [(i1+1, i2+n+1) for i1, l in enumerate(labels_1) 
                                 for i2 in np.where(labels_2 != l)[0]]
```

> [(1,8),(1,9),(1,10),(2,8),...]

Though, I am not sure this is the most efficient way.

Comment: What if the two matrices labels1 and labels2 are not equal?

Comment: @JoseRamon It should work whenever labels_1 and labels_2 are equal or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
outp = []
len1 = len(labels) // 2 # assume initially labels was [label1, label1]
label1 = labels[:len1]
label2 = labels[len1:]
set1 = set(label1)
for v in set1:
    eq1 = np.where(label1 == v)[0] + 1
    eq2 = np.where(label2 == v)[0] + len1 + 1
    outp.append(np.transpose([np.tile(eq1, len(eq2)), np.repeat(eq2, len(eq1))]))
outp = np.concatenate(outp).tolist()

# Edit: Find "negative pairs"
eq3 = np.indices((len1, ))[0][np.in1d(label2, list(set1), invert=True)] + len1 + 1
outn = np.transpose([np.tile(np.arange(len1), len(eq3)), np.repeat(eq3, len1)]).tolist()
```

Comment: How can I return the negative pairs in that case?

Comment: I tried to change label1 == v to != but it seems that it is not that simple.

Comment: @JoseRamon `v` is drawn from `set1` which is a set of all distinct values from `label1` and therefore condition `label1 != v` will never be true. That is, if you change `label1 == v` to `label1 != v`, `eq1` will always be an empty array (in the sense of a zero-length array). What you need to do instead is to find all elements from `label2` that are *different* from any element in `set1`. I will edit my answer to show this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

My solution used numpy broadcasting and [np.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
x, y = np.where(label1[np.newaxis, :] == label2[:, np.newaxis])
result = np.vstack([x, y+len(label1)]).T + 1
```

I thought this was an efficient/numpy way to solve your problem.  But, tarashypka's solution is faster on larger data sets.  (Anyone know why?)

```
def where_method(a, b):
    x, y = np.where(a[np.newaxis, :] == b[:, np.newaxis])
    return np.vstack([x, y+len(labels1)]).T + 1

def for_append_method(a, b):
    length1 = len(a)
    positive_pairs = []
    for ii, label in enumerate(a, 1):
        for other in np.where(b == label)[0] + length1 + 1:
            positive_pairs.append((ii, other))
    return positive_pairs

labels1 = np.sort(np.random.randint(low=10, high=7500, size=10000))
labels2 = labels1

%timeit where_method(labels1, labels2)
%timeit for_append_method(labels1, labels2)
```

```
326 ms ± 2.98 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
122 ms ± 1.71 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```